# Path along linked values taking the lowest value each time

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, igraph

I have a `data.table` with two columns "From" and "To" as follows:

```
data.table(From = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5),
           To = c(3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,5,6,6))
```

The `data.table` will always be sorted as shown in the example above, with "From" and "To" values increasing from smallest to largest.

I need to find a 'path' starting from the first 'From' (which will always be '1'), through to the last 'To' value, subject to always choosing the lowest 'To' value.
In the above example, I would have 1 --> 3, then 3 --> 4, then 4 --> 5, then finally 5 --> 6.

I then want to return in a vector 1, 3, 4, 5, and 6, representing the linked values.

The only way that I can think of doing it is using a while or for loop and looping through each group of 'From' values and iteratively choosing the smallest. That seems inefficient though and will probably be very slow on my actual data set which is over 100,000 rows long.

Are there any `data.table`-like solutions?
I also thought that maybe igraph would have a method for this, but I must admit that I currently have pretty much zero knowledge of this function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Phil

EDIT:

Thanks for all the responses so far.
My example/explanation wasn't a great one sorry, as I didn't explain that the 'From' / 'To' pairs don't need to go all the way through to the end value of the 'To' column.

Using the example from the comments below:

```
dt <- data.table(From = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5), 
                   To = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6))
```

The output would simply be a vector of c(1, 3), as it will start at 1, choose the lowest value which is 3, and then because there are no 'From' values of '3', it wouldn't continue any further.

Another example:

```
dt <- data.table(From = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
                   To = c(2,3,4,5,6,4,7,8,9))
```

The intended output here is a vector c(1,2,5); following the path 1 --> 2, then 2 --> 5, at which point it stops as there is no '5' value in the "From" column.

Hopefully, that makes sense, and apologies for the lack of clarity in the original question.

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Not data.table like, but if i understood correctly, you can order `To` in increasing order, then get it's unique values (or the other way around), then append `From[1]` to the beginning: `with(df, c(From[1], unique(To[order(To)])))`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding posted another example dataset: `dt <- data.table(From = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5), To = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6))` Can you tell us what is the desired output there? And consider any other edge cases from your real-life scenario as well.

Comment: Thanks @arg0naut91, good suggestion. Please see my edits above with this example and one further one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
dt %>%
  group_by(From) %>%
  slice_min(To) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame() %>%
  ego(
    order = sum((m <- membership(components(.))) == m[names(m) == "1"]),
    nodes = "1",
    mode = "out"
  ) %>%
  pluck(1) %>%
    names() %>%
    as.numeric()
```

or simpler with `subcomponent` (as [@clp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74589335/12158757) did)

```
dt %>%
  group_by(From) %>%
  slice_min(To) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame() %>%
  subcomponent(v = "1", mode = "out") %>%
  names() %>%
  as.integer()
```

which gives

- For the first new updated data

```
[1] 1 3
```

- For the second updaed data

```
[1] 1 2 5
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding. That works really well for the example above. Unfortunately I didn't fully explain the various edge cases that may arise which won't work for the code above. Can you please have a look at the revised examples that I added?

Comment: @Phil I think you can make it using `subcomponent` (preferrable) or `ego` if you stick with `igraph`. Please see the update.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming an ordered *From* and *To* list this may work.

It first groups by *From*, compresses by *To*, then excludes non-matching *From-To* values using `shift`.

If jumps are missing (e.g. *To* 3 but *From* 3 missing) it prints `NULL`

```
dt[, .(frst = first(To)), From][
  , if(all((frst %in% From)[1:(.N - 1)])){
      c(1, unique(frst[From == shift(frst, type = "lag", fill = T)]))}]
[1] 1 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Nice `data.table` answer! +1!

Comment: Thanks @Andre Wildberg. That works well for the example that I posted, but unfortunately I didn't explain the full criteria very well. Can you please have a look at my edited question / examples?

Answer (score 2):

Using from `Igraph` and `subcomponents()`.

After ThomasisCoding's comment, I realized that `graph_from_data_frame` creates a graph by name.
This is a waste of memory (and time) if the graph is large (1E6).
Note also that `graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(...))` is much faster.

```
dt2 <- setNames(aggregate(dt$To, list(dt$From), "min"), c("From", "To") )
g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(dt2), directed=TRUE) 
as.numeric(as_ids(subcomponent(g, 1, mode="out")))
```

First attempt.

```
dt2 <- setNames(aggregate(dt$To, list(dt$From), "min"), c("From", "To") )
g <- graph_from_data_frame(dt2, directed=TRUE) 
as.numeric(as_ids(subcomponent(g, 1, mode="out")))
```

Comment: nice solution with `subcomponent`, it plays the magic that I almost forgot about it! +1! By the way, you should use `"1"` instead of `1` when you index the vertex by name unless you know it `vid`.

Comment: Good point. My intention was to create a graph without vertex names. To save memory when the dataframe is very large (1E6). That is why I used 1 instead of "1".

Comment: I also tried dfs() and bfs(). These functions are slower.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to get the other answers to work with certain tables. E.g.,

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)
library(purrr)

dt <- data.table(
  From = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5),
  To = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6)
)

fPath1 <- function(dt) {
  setorder(dt, From, To)[, wt := fifelse(rleid(To)==1,1,Inf), From] %>%
    graph_from_data_frame() %>%
    set_edge_attr(name = "weight", value = dt[, wt]) %>%
    shortest_paths(min(dt[, From]), max(dt[, To])) %>%
    pluck(1) %>%
    unlist(use.names = FALSE)
}

fPath2 <- function(dt) {
  dt[, .SD[which.min(To)], From] %>%
    graph_from_data_frame() %>%
    shortest_paths(min(dt[, From]), max(dt[, To])) %>%
    pluck(1) %>%
    unlist(use.names = FALSE)
}

fPath3 <- function(dt) {
  dt[, .(frst = first(To)), From][
    , if(all((frst %in% From)[1:(.N - 1)])){
      c(1, unique(frst[From == shift(frst, type = "lag", fill = T)]))}]
}

fPath1(dt)
#> [1] 1 6
fPath2(dt)
#> Warning in shortest_paths(., min(dt[, From]), max(dt[, To])): At core/paths/
#> unweighted.c:368 : Couldn't reach some vertices.
#> integer(0)
fPath3(dt)
#> NULL
```

This `igraph` solution seems to work based on a little more extensive testing:

```
fPath4 <- function(dt) {
  g <- graph_from_data_frame(dt)
  E(g)$weight <- (dt$To - dt$From)^2
  as.integer(V(g)[shortest_paths(g, V(g)[1], V(g)[name == dt$To[nrow(dt)]])$vpath[[1]]]$name)
}

fPath4(dt)
#> [1] 1 4 6
```

Answer (score 0):

A sequential solution is feasable.
Copying one million dataframe lines took 8 seconds on my system.

```
n <- 1E6
df1 <- data.frame(from=sample(n), to=sample(n))
path <- c()
system.time(
for (i in seq(nrow(df1)) ){
  path[length(path) + 1] <- df1[i, "to"]   # avoid copying.
}
)
mean(path)
length(path)
```

Output.

```
[1] 500000.5
[1] 1000000
```

Updated after last edit of Phil.
The first step is to simplify the input (df).

```
## Select min(To) by From.
if (nrow(df) > 0) { df2 <- setNames(aggregate(df$To, list(df$From), "min"), c("From", "To") )
} else              df2 <- df
```

Set path to first start node and
subsequently append end nodes.

```
## Let tt is maximal outgoing node upto now.
path <- df2[1,1]
tt <- df2[1,1]
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df2))){
  if      (df2[i, 1] < tt) next
  else if (df2[i,1] == tt) { tt <- df2[i, 2]
                             path[length(path) + 1] <- df2[i, 2]
                           }
  else                     break
}
head(path)
```

Output:

```
[1] 1 3 4 5 6 , df as in first example.
[1] 1 2 5     , df as in another example.
```